# How can I detect errors like missing images in a storyboard?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode-storyboard, ibtool

Sometimes I can't be noticed missing images and missing IBActions when I'm continuously refactoring file names and method names.

What I can find is following which is an example usage of ibtool:

```
       ibtool --warnings --errors --notices file.nib > alerts.plist
          alerts.plist  will  contain  all warning, error, and notice mes-
          sages from file.nib.
```

But it doesn't warn about missing images nor missing IBActions.

Is there any way to efficiently detect these errors?